# Can I input a video signal into my HTC phone to use it as an external monitor of a camera?

Tags: usb, external-display, htc-evo-3d, mhl

I'd like to use my HTC Evo 3D as an external monitor for my Canon 7D camera. The Canon 7D has a HDMI output. It also has an USB port, naturally.

I was wondering whether this would be possible. I think the USB/MHL port on HTC Evo 3D is for output only and it cannot receive any signal inputs. Is that right?

That would leave the USB port for this. But I still don't know how to achieve it.

I want to achieve something like this:

[image: photo of camera with external microphone inputs and monitor]

Answer (score 1):

If your HTC phone has OTG support. You can use one of these [USB OTG adapters](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00AYPEL56). Then you can plug your 70D using a mini USB cable and then plug it in to the OTG cable and plug it into your phone. Then you can download an app such as [DSLR Controller](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.chainfire.dslrcontroller&hl=en) and you should see  live feed of your 70D on the phone.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there are several apps on google play that will support several external cameras via USB, and I believe they allow for control of camera via android as well. Just search for Canon Camera Controller.

Comment: I think instead of controller the OP wants something like external monitor.